# Add PlusMinus to Accordion Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Accordion Menu has a Counter to count the Submenus. I want to change it to Plus Minus.
If there is a Submenu than "Plus" should be add if is closed, if is opened than a Minus.

If there is no SubMenu than nothing should be added.

The Counter code

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function(index, e){
      var count = $(e).find('li').length;
      var content = '<span class="cnt">' + count + '</span>';
      $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5abCc/)

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yxxF4/) 's a workaround for you. Play with `span.plusminus` style as you desire.

Comment: @BatuZet Thanks for the Code! At loading the Page the state of the span is everytime "+" even if the Menu is opened.

Comment: Then when adding those spans, you can add them as `-` inside since they are gonna be opened as default.

Comment: @BatuZet Thanks for your help! Could you maybe tell me also how I can change the Class Name instead using .text() ? I want to use FontAwesome for the Menu.

Comment: Class Name? `var content = '<span class="cnt">' + count + '</span><span class="plusminus">+</span>';` this is where you add the `span` and simply change  `class="plusminus"` to  `class="whatever_you_want"`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Nope. [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) FontAwesome is using CSS Icons. Thats why if state is changed than css class name should be changed too [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Oh. Then you need to use `.removeClass().addClass()` method. Or `.toggleClass()`. [CHECK HERE](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could achieve this by first getting two icons 1. Plus 2. Minus and putting something like this in your css:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_plus.png) 90% center no-repeat;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
    background: url(images/icon_minus.png) 90% center no-repeat;
}
```

Here my menu is as follows:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Now with jquery check if your menu has a submenu using:

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
```

And add the two css classes you made and drop down using jquery. I made a jfiddle as that would be too much to put here.

Here you go [Jfiddle - accordian plus minus](http://jsfiddle.net/jzY2f/)

Hope this helps! Not all of the code is mine. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the `Accordion Jquery-Ui` for that

[Jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons)

Comment: I have looked at Accordion UI and to change to it, I have to edit many files from the System.